# Raspberry pi 3 model B

Tags: raspberry-pi3

I have 32gb memory card and a raspberry pi 3 model B board I want to do project in windows 10 IoT core os and an  another project in raspbian os 
Is it possible to install both os in same sd card?

Comment: I don't know if this is considered off topic for SO or not, but I've always gotten better help with pi related issues on https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I would recommend looking into BerryBoot

Comment: What about noobs??

Comment: yes you can, as if you have installed dual os in your computer. I haven't tried myself.

Answer (score 0):

your memory card is 32 gb

but you can not install 2 os in one memory card.

Answer (score 0):

use 16-16 gb memory card with one raspberry pi but you can't use one memory with two os in raspberry pi have't  virtual software or partition window . Use raspbian that's best software
thanks you
if you have any query regarding raspberry pi so connect sajanarora517@gmail.com 
information free for all